# How to make gvfs-smb always use UTF8

Tags: 10.10, gnome, samba, gvfs, cifs

The problem is that if I make an entry in `/etc/fstab` to mount a samba share I can give the option `iocharset=utf8` and this then mounts the share correctly and in the right encoding with special characters displayed correctly.

Gnomes automount system for some reason never gets this right and I can find nowhere to change its settings.

Is there a way to make it always use UTF8 by default?

This is with Ubuntu 10.10 and the system can display the characters involved.

Answer (score 1):

gvfs-smb uses libsmbclient which uses the normal configuration for Samba for encoding. Have you tried setting `unix charset = utf-8` in your `/etc/samba/smb.conf`?